# fluid bootstrap layout empty spaces

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i recently started using bootstrap and encountered the following problem: horizontal scroll bar appears
much earlier then it should be. Red square on the screenshot below shows a blank space next to the form thas is 
not filled with any information, hidden tables/divs.

**HTML**

```
<section class="content"><div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span10 article">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="section">
    <h4>Online Application</h4>
        <div class="row-fluid form-horizontal">
        <div class="span6">
            <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                input type="text" name="contact_name_1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="contact_name_2">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="contact_email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Home Phone</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="contact_phone_home">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Cell Phone</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="contact_phone_cell">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                       <input type="button" value="Start Application" onClick="obertka25()">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLZCi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you're including `bootstrap-responsive.css`.  `bootstrap.css` only includes the fixed-width layout rules.

Also, your `<section>` element isn't closed, and your formatting makes it a little hard to tell visually whether each div is properly closed.  That could also be causing the scrollbar problem.

As for the white space on the right, that's because your div has `span10` which is only 10/12ths of a row.  Use `span12` to fill the whole horizontal space.  I'm not sure from your question whether you wanted the white space or not.

For more information, see [Bootstrap layouts](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#layouts) and scroll down a bit to the "Fluid layouts" section.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried to wrap all of the code in an element with the container-fluid class - didnt help. All tags are closed, i accidentally didnt select all of html :). White space placed properly, i wanted 10/12ths of a row to be filled with form space.

Comment: Hmm, in that case, can you create a jsfiddle with all the html and css your page is using?

Comment: Edited my post with the answer.

Comment: You might need to update your bootstrap.  What I suggested does work with bootstrap 2.3.1.  See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4JmjJ/2/  I added a missing `</section>` and missing `</div>`.

Comment: I updated bootstrap, didnt help. :( In your jsfiddle you forgot to copypaste my own style.css, from the previous jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/4JmjJ/3/ here you can see its still not working right

Comment: This is turning into a discussion, which is not the focus of SO.  Since the problem lies within your CSS, and you didn't include any CSS code in the question, I think it's best to write a new question once you've isolated the problem.